# How can i center the text if the fantawesome icon has a different size than the two below?

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1iNb.png)

As you guys can see, i centered the items but due to the first one is a little bit smaller the title and text on the right is not aligned with the two bellow. I could add some padding to center it manually but im not sure if that is a good practice, and also if it is going to affect the order when i add the media query to make it responsive and all of that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/css/all.css">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #eff1ed;
                font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            }
            
            /* Header and nav bar */
            header {
                display: flex;
            }
            .logo-guitar {
                padding: 2% 1% 3% 2%;
            }
            .luthier-name {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 1.5% 0 0 1%;
            }
            #nav-bar {
                display: flex;
                text-align: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                flex-direction: row;
            }
            .nav-link {
                width: 94px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 2px auto;
                padding-top: 15%;
                color: #131b23;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            h1 {
                font-family: "Satisfy", cursive;
                font-size: 3rem;
            }
            
            /* email form */
            
            .email-form {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #email {
                height: 25px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #submit {
                width: 80%;
                margin-top: 5%;
                background-color: #ffe121;
                border: 0;
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 35px;
                font-family: inherit;
                font-size: large;
            }
            
            /* Features */
            
            .fa-solid {
                color: #e3170a;
                font-size: 4rem;
            }
            
            .features {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .p-description {
                max-width: 90vh;
            }
            section {
                padding-top: 10%;
            }
            .icon {
                padding-right: 3%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
        <div class="features">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-fire"></i></div>
            <div>
                <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
                <p class="p-description">
                    Our guitars are built with the best amazonian wood. This will
                    increase the longevity of your purchase.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="features">
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-truck-fast"></i>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Shipping</h2>
                <p class="p-description">
                    We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished
                    making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="features">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-check"></i></div>
            <div>
                <h2>Satisfaction</h2>
                <p class="p-description">
                    For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or
                    faults and we will check and test the quality of your instrument.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to know whats the best option in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using fixed-width Fontawesome icons by adding `fa-fw` to the classes (see https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/fixed-width). For instance:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-fire fa-fw"></i>
```

Comment: What a great tip!